# Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3.1 compiler

Tags: ios, swift

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3.1 compiler:
/Users/imac/Desktop/PixelPhoto/PixelPhotoSDK.framework/Modules/PixelPhotoSDK.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

I have try many way to solve this but I can't resolve this issue.
I am trying with toolchain and convert code to latest version also.

Answer (score 0):

This is a framework issue. Apparently *PixelPhotoSDK.framework* has been built using either Xcode version **11.5**, **11.6** or **11.7** and more importantly without the **BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION** build configuration set to **YES**.

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about it, if you are not **the creator** of this framework, other than go back to previous Xcode versions.

The creator of the framework can do one of 2 things: (or even better both)

- Rebuild the framework using those old Xcode versions but with **BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION** configuration set to **YES**. (that will enable the ability to be used from an app that is build with different Swift compiler version. See [Module Stability](https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-1-released/) feature available since Swift 5.1)
- Rebuild the framework using the Xcode version that you are currently using (probably version 12.2)